# "Lights Off" puzzle in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm a newbie in Tkinter and I've managed to make the "Lights Off" puzzle using Tkinter with Python 3.

The game starts by presenting 9 buttons arranged in a 3x3 matrix. The text of the button will be either 0 (which denotes that the light is off) and 1 (which denotes that the light is on). Clicking on a button inverts the text in it as well as the text in the adjacent buttons.

The game is won once all the lights are off, i.e, all the buttons have 0 as their text.

Right now, the program does nothing when the game is won. I haven't made that part yet.

Is there any room for improvement?

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
from random import randint

def button_text_changer(val, buttons):
    '''Changes text of buttons'''

    buttons[val].config(text = str(int(buttons[val].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1)) # Change the text of the button pressed to 0 if it was 1 and 1 if it was 0

    # Change text of adjacent buttons
    if val == 0:
        buttons[1].config(text = str(int(buttons[1].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[3].config(text = str(int(buttons[3].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[4].config(text = str(int(buttons[4].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
    if val == 1:
        buttons[0].config(text = str(int(buttons[0].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[2].config(text = str(int(buttons[2].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[3].config(text = str(int(buttons[3].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[4].config(text = str(int(buttons[4].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[5].config(text = str(int(buttons[5].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
    if val == 2:
        buttons[1].config(text = str(int(buttons[1].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[4].config(text = str(int(buttons[4].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[5].config(text = str(int(buttons[5].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
    if val == 3:
        buttons[0].config(text = str(int(buttons[0].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[1].config(text = str(int(buttons[1].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[4].config(text = str(int(buttons[4].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[6].config(text = str(int(buttons[6].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[7].config(text = str(int(buttons[7].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
    if val == 4:
        buttons[0].config(text = str(int(buttons[0].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[1].config(text = str(int(buttons[1].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[2].config(text = str(int(buttons[2].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[3].config(text = str(int(buttons[3].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[5].config(text = str(int(buttons[5].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[6].config(text = str(int(buttons[6].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[7].config(text = str(int(buttons[7].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[8].config(text = str(int(buttons[8].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
    if val == 5:
        buttons[1].config(text = str(int(buttons[1].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[2].config(text = str(int(buttons[2].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[4].config(text = str(int(buttons[4].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[7].config(text = str(int(buttons[7].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[8].config(text = str(int(buttons[8].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
    if val == 6:
        buttons[3].config(text = str(int(buttons[3].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[4].config(text = str(int(buttons[4].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[7].config(text = str(int(buttons[7].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
    if val == 7:
        buttons[3].config(text = str(int(buttons[3].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[4].config(text = str(int(buttons[4].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[5].config(text = str(int(buttons[5].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[6].config(text = str(int(buttons[6].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[7].config(text = str(int(buttons[7].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
    if val == 8:
        buttons[4].config(text = str(int(buttons[4].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[5].config(text = str(int(buttons[5].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
        buttons[7].config(text = str(int(buttons[7].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))

def get_rand_list():
    '''Returns a list of size 9 with zeros and ones which are randomly chosen'''

    rand_list = []

    for i in range(9):
        if randint(0, 1) == 0:
            rand_list.append(0)
        else:
            rand_list.append(1)

    # Checking if all lights are off
    all_lights_off = True
    for i in range(9):
        if rand_list[i] == 1:
            all_lights_off = False

    if all_lights_off:
        rand_list = get_rand_list() # Generate random list once again
    else:
        return rand_list

def add_Buttons(root, rand_list):
    '''Add buttons to root(first argument), with their text corresponding to the values in the list provided(second argument)'''

    row = 0
    buttons = []

    for i in range(9):

        if i != 0 and i % 3 == 0:
            row += 1

        button = Button(root, text = rand_list[i], font = ('arial', 25, 'bold'))
        button.grid(row = row, column = i % 3)

        buttons.append(button)

    for i in range(9):
        buttons[i].config(command = partial(button_text_changer, i, buttons))

def start_game():
    '''Starts the Lights Off game'''

    root = Tk()

    add_Buttons(root, get_rand_list())

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_game()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Don't repeat yourself

This is really a bit excessive repetition:

> ```
> if val == 0:
>     buttons[1].config(text = str(int(buttons[1].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
>     buttons[3].config(text = str(int(buttons[3].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
>     buttons[4].config(text = str(int(buttons[4].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
> if val == 1:
>     buttons[0].config(text = str(int(buttons[0].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
>     buttons[2].config(text = str(int(buttons[2].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
>     buttons[3].config(text = str(int(buttons[3].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
>     buttons[4].config(text = str(int(buttons[4].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
>     buttons[5].config(text = str(int(buttons[5].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))
> # ...
> ```

A helper function can make this a lot easier and safer, for example:

```
def update_buttons(*idx_list):
    for index in idx_list:
        buttons[index].config(text = str(int(buttons[index].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))

if val == 0:
    update_buttons(1, 3, 4)
elif val == 1:
    update_buttons(0, 2, 3, 4, 5)
# ...
```

Notice also that I changed the mutually exclusive `if-if` to `if-elif`.

#### Simplify

This can be written simpler:

> ```
>     if randint(0, 1) == 0:
>         rand_list.append(0)
>     else:
>         rand_list.append(1)
> ```

Like this:

```
    rand_list.append(randint(0, 1))
```

#### Use list comprehensions

This loop can be rewritten with a list comprehension:

> ```
> for i in range(9):
>     if randint(0, 1) == 0:
>         rand_list.append(0)
>     else:
>         rand_list.append(1)
> ```

Like this:

```
rand_list = [randint(0, 1) for _ in range(9)]
```

#### Issues with iteration

In this piece,
notice that after `all_lights_off` is set to `False`,
there's no need to iterate further, you can `break`.

> ```
> all_lights_off = True
> for i in range(9):
>     if rand_list[i] == 1:
>         all_lights_off = False
> ```

But even better, the entire loop can be replaced with this:

```
all_lights_off = not any(rand_list)
```

`any` returns true if any element in the list is *truthy*.
In this example, it returns when there is a 1 in the list anywhere.
So, `not any(rand_list)` will only be `True` when all values are 0,
because 0 is *falsy*.

#### Dead code

The assignment `rand_list = ...` in the `if` branch is dead code,
because this is the last statement in the function,
so the value is assigned but it will be never used.
Also note that when `all_lights_off` is `True`,
the function will return `None`, instead of a random list.

> ```
> if all_lights_off:
>     rand_list = get_rand_list() # Generate random list once again
> else:
>     return rand_list
> ```

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks. BTW, could you change `buttons[5].config(text = str(int(buttons[1].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))` to `buttons[5].config(text = str(int(buttons[5].config('text')[-1]) ^ 1))` in your answer?

Comment: There you go :-)